# Create incremented column in entity created from stored proc - sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a stored proc which will feed an entity from two tables in sql server. Neither table has a pk. I need my view to have an incremented column.

So far, I have this:

```
    @iNodeLevel int,
    @iParentNodeId bigint

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sQuery varchar (2000)

    IF @iNodeLevel >= 5

    RETURN

    ELSE

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET @sQuery = 'SELECT * FROM DataView.dbo.Tree
    WHERE L' + CAST((@iNodeLevel + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'TID IS NULL
    AND L' + CAST((@iNodeLevel) AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'TID = ' + CAST((@iParentNodeId) AS VARCHAR(10))

    EXEC (@sQuery)
    --dbo.DV_GetTreeNodes 1,1
END


GO
```

to get the info I want. I just want to also include the aforementioned incremented column.

How do you do this?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2005+ you can simulate an auto-increment column with ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: Pardon me, will edit... meant to say stored proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [analytic `ROW_NUMBER()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (myColumn) AS IncrementedColumn
FROM TODS26_DataView.dbo.v_PowerSystemCIMTree
....
```

This will assign the incremented value based on how `myColumn` sorts.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed... Only thing was that I got an error saying, "The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY." So all I needed to do was, "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( ORDER BY myColumn) ...

Then it worked great. Just wanted to explicitly record what I needed to do in case someone else has this problem.

Thanks again!!!

Comment: Excellent, and thanks for the heads-up on the first query's problems. I'll remove it; no point leaving a bad query in.